# Flutter upgrade

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

After upgrading Flutter, and when i create a new project i'm getting `+` lines  :

```
Creating project prgh...
Running "flutter pub get" in prgh...
Resolving dependencies in prgh... (1.6s)
+ async 2.10.0
+ boolean_selector 2.1.1
+ characters 1.2.1
+ clock 1.1.1
+ collection 1.17.0 (1.17.1 available)
+ cupertino_icons 1.0.5
+ fake_async 1.3.1
+ flutter 0.0.0 from sdk flutter
+ flutter_lints 2.0.1
+ flutter_test 0.0.0 from sdk flutter
+ js 0.6.5 (0.6.7 available)
+ lints 2.0.1
+ matcher 0.12.13 (0.12.14 available)
+ material_color_utilities 0.2.0
+ meta 1.8.0 (1.9.0 available)
+ path 1.8.2 (1.8.3 available)
+ sky_engine 0.0.99 from sdk flutter
+ source_span 1.9.1
+ stack_trace 1.11.0
+ stream_channel 2.1.1
+ string_scanner 1.2.0
+ term_glyph 1.2.1
+ test_api 0.4.16 (0.4.18 available)
+ vector_math 2.1.4
Changed 24 dependencies in prgh!
Wrote 127 files.

All done!
You can find general documentation for Flutter at: https://docs.flutter.dev/
Detailed API documentation is available at: https://api.flutter.dev/
If you prefer video documentation, consider:
https://www.youtube.com/c/flutterdev

In order to run your application, type:

  $ cd prgh
  $ flutter run

Your application code is in prgh/lib/main.dart.
```

My question is :  what does the `+` lines mean?. is there anything i'm supposed to do?.

Comment: They mark a new item on the list of resolved dependencies, nothing special

Comment: Oh ok thanks. I was a bit confused about what this was for, and now it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

these are the dependencies/packages that I think updated in it's latest version!